# finding the names and view of all apache environment variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, environment-variables

I just want to know if there is a link with all of the environment variables in apache and what they look like when they are printed out.

The reason is i am trying to write some regex for .htacess mod_rewrite, but i don't know what these variables are printing. it's hard to write regex when im not sure what is printed, i keep getting them wrong. 
Is there a list somewhere i am missing.

Trust me googling is easier than posting a question and waiting for response and people not quite sure what you are asked.

I can't seem to find a google source.

Eg %{THE_REQUEST} GET /index.php HTTP/1.1

The real problem i am having is i have this .htaccess file

```
    # Do not remove this line, otherwise mod_rewrite rules will stop working

RewriteBase /

Options +Multiviews

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .css

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .js

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On


#NC not case sensitive
#L last rule don't process futher
#R 301 changes the url to what you want

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.host56\.com 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.host56.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^demo(.*)$ finished$1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home/$1
```

I keep getting redirected to the error page
I am trying to get to

```
example.host56.com/home/
```

But it keeps leading me to errors. The home folder has a index.php file inside of it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mod_rewrite variable cheat sheet: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html

The rule here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home/$1
```

Is looping. The reason is because the `%{REQUEST_URI}` variable *always starts with a `/`*, and you're not using either the "`^`" or "`$`" to denote matching boundaries, so that condition will always be true. Since it's always true, the rule will always be replied. And since the rewrite engine continually loops until the URI stops changing (or until you've reached the internal recursion limit, causing a 500 error), the pattern always matches. Try changing it to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home/$1
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ home/$1
```